# Issue with creating a scoped IIF sum in SSRS Matrix

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to create a column outside of the groups to summarise the totals according to criteria in the sum line.  If I use the following expression

```
=sum(iif(Fields!VATApplicable="NO",Fields!Amount.Value,0))
```

It gives an error when run

if I try to add a scope to the value amount then it gives that I cannot add a scope there.

```
=sum(iif(Fields!VATApplicable="NO",sum(Fields!Amount.Value,"JournalList"),0))
```

Anyone able to help me structure this to get it to work?

Thanks
[image]

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of the report design?  Just a little unclear on whether you're adding a separate list/tablix item separated from the data or if it's in the same table and it would help to see how things are laid out.

Comment: Added screenshot above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about you create Extra column Let's call it VAT applicable and Set it as Fields!Amount.Value only when Fields!VATApplicable="NO"

This will contain Amount only for Rows where you have VATApplicable="NO".

Now at the bottom you could simply Add Total outside which will give you Grand Total.

Comment: I need both the yes and no, but that would just mean two columns instead of one.

Comment: Yes, I thought you need only "No" as mentioned in Question.

Comment: Nope, but simple enough to do the query having both columns and an union to seperate the datasets.  worked perfectly, Thanks.